# How Python pandas data-frame merge works in this case?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge 2 excel sheet using pandas.
but on inner merge it misses 1 record which is on both data frames.
and on left merge it gives half data.

```
df1=pd.read_excel('output_may_tv.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet2',index_col=None, header=None,names=['url'])

df2=pd.read_excel('output_may_2.xlsx',sheet_name='metadata',index_col=None, header=None,names=['title','synopsis','rs','rh','bs','bh','url','n','e','site'])


result1=df1.merge(df2,on='url')
```

initially, result1 gives 1 URL less after doing

```
result1=df1.merge(df2,how='left')
```

it shows url but other columns data are missing on that merged row

please anybody explain to me how to solve this.

Comment: Can you share the XLSX files (or part of them)? I think this can be solved with that input.

Comment: thanks guys, @Erfan your solution worked and also Josh for showing interest in my question.

Comment: Glad it helped, will post as answer so you can accept :) @Adarsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the url's which are missing exactly the same, or are their difference in capital and non-capital letters or whitespaces? Convert your column to uppercase and remove whitespaces:

```
df1['url'] = df1['url'].str.upper().str.strip()
```

And do the same for df2. 
Then try to do the merge again

Comment: change df to df1